# relative links to third party proxied domain still point to old domain

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-rewrite

I have a proxy rule pointing www.example.com/support to our third party support site (www.support.example.com/support). Looking at the page source, the links are all relative example:

```
     <a href="/support/answers/subjectN">
```

However when navigating to the site via the proxy and mousing over and clicking the links it reverts to the third party domain. I have the mod_proxy_http module loaded with the following rules but it also doesn't appear to work:

```
ProxyPass /support https://example.custhelp.com/support
ProxyPassReverse /app https://example.custhelp.com/support
 <Location app/>
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://example.custhelp.com/app/(.*)$ https://www.exmample.com/app/$1 [R]
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app/
 </Location>
```

Comment: Removing edit to put in original post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually tied to the fact that in apache you need the  "SetOutputFilter" to actually tell apache to pass documents through mod_proxy_html module. My testing browser had compression enabled, and the web server gave the client the page compressed, which mod_proxy_html will not be able to understand. This line decompresses documents (if compressed), runs it through proxy-html, then recompresses it (if supported).

```
 SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
```